# Accessing uv attributes with python

Tags: python, uv

ive found scattered information on how to access the uv attributes of a mesh. I cant quiet understand the procedure here. All i want to do is get the position of the uvs for the selected vertices in the viewport. But i keep running into all the errors. Any help or suggestions are welcomed.

```
import bpy
obj = bpy.context.active_object
#first lets make sure this is a mesh
if obj.type == 'MESH' and obj.data.uv_layers:
    print("this is a mesh and has uvs")
    
    mesh = obj.data # Get the attributes of the mesh
    cur_uv_layer = mesh.uv_layers.active.data
    obj.update_from_editmode() #Loads edit mode tata into object data.
    
    sel_verts = [v for v in mesh.vertices if v.select]
    
    if len(sel_verts)>0:
        
        for uvs in sel_verts:
            uv_data = cur_uv_layer[uvs.index].uv
            print("UV:", uv_data[0], uv_data[1] )

else:
    print("This mesh does not have uvs!")
```

Comment: Please provide the error message, reproduction steps etc, next time. "But i keep running into all the errors" is really not helpful.

Comment: That was part of my issue, there were no errors. My script wouldnt find anything therefore it printed "This mesh does not have uvs". Sorry for the lack of info

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the way you wrote the script (`update_from_editmode`), you just need to add this line

```
bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode="OBJECT")  # here
obj = bpy.context.active_object
```

to make sure you are in object mode before.

> But i keep running into all the errors

You run into *one type* of error when you are in edit mode in this line `uv_data = cur_uv_layer[uvs.index].uv`:

```
IndexError: bpy_prop_collection[index]: index 2 out of range, size 0
```

because the selected vertices (i selected one with index 2) in edit mode have not been [loaded into the object data](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Object.html#bpy.types.Object.update_from_editmode).

Side note:

```
for uvs in sel_verts:
    uv_data = cur_uv_layer[uvs.index].uv
```

is meh. Better is something like:

```
for vert in sel_verts:
    uv_data = cur_uv_layer[vert.index].uv # this makes sense
```